# How do I use a SQL If statement here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How do I use IF THEN ELSE Statement here? As not everyone takes leave or does overtime. I made a query with help from the people here, I manage to make the IdeaTable and edited it to make it suit my query even more. But currently I am facing a new issue.

Scenario: EmployeeID 123 applied for leave on 2018-05-06 for 4 hours but the roster is not out yet.

Below are the tables and data

**Employee**:

```
EmplyeeeID | Username | Password | GivenName | FamilyName | TeamID | ContactNo | StaffType
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123         123        abc        John          Snow        1         999          1
  1234        1234       abcd       Jack         Waller       2         223          1 
  12345       12345      abcde       Ali           Saw        1         123          1
  123456      123456     abcdef     Peter         Peter       2         223          1
  1234567     1234567    abcdeg     Bryan         Peter       1         333          1
```

**Roster**:

```
Duty_ID | EmployeeID |      Date        | ShiftType | ShiftDuration
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   2       123             2018-05-05         1          8.25
   4       1234            2018-05-04         1          8.25
   5       12345           2018-05-05         1          8.25
   7       123456          2018-05-04         1          8.25
   8       1234567         2018-05-05         1          8.25
```

**Overtime**:

```
OTID | EmployeeID |     Date     | OT_Duration | OT_Reason
------------------------------------------------------------
 2        1234        2018-05-04        2        Cover Duty
```

**Leave**:

```
LeaveID | EmployeeID |   Date    | Duration_Off | Reason
----------------------------------------------------------
 3            123      2018-05-05        2         NIL
 4            123      2018-05-06        4         NIL
```

**IdealTable** (via query)

```
   Date    | EmployeeID | GivenName | FamilyName | TeamID | ShiftType | ShiftDuration | Duration_Off | OT_Duration | Total_Hours
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-05-05      123         John         Snow         1         1             8.25            2             0            6.25
2018-05-04      1234        Jack        Waller        1         1             8.25            0             2            10.25
2018-05-05      12345       Ali           Saw         1         1             8.25            0             0            8.25
2018-05-04      123456      Peter         Peter       1         1             8.25            0             0            8.25
2018-05-05      1234567     Bryan         Peter       1         1             8.25            2             0            8.25
```

[image: Problem]

As you can see from the picture Row 2 doesn't make sense, as Employee 123 only took leave on 2018-05-06, so How I make it not display it?

My query

```
SELECT 
    r.Date,
    e.EmployeeID,
    e.GivenName,
    e.FamilyName,
    e.TeamID,
    r.ShiftType,
    COALESCE(s.Shift_Duration, 0) AS Shift_Duration,
    s.Shift_Description,
    COALESCE(l.Duration_Off, 0) AS Duration_Off,
    COALESCE(o.OT_Duration, 0) AS OT_Duration,
    (COALESCE(s.Shift_Duration, 0) + COALESCE(o.OT_Duration, 0) - COALESCE(l.Duration_Off, 0)) AS Total_Hours
FROM 
    Employee e
    INNER JOIN
    Roster r ON  e.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID 
    LEFT JOIN
    Leave l ON e.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID 
    LEFT JOIN 
    Overtime o ON  e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN 
    ShiftID s ON r.ShiftType = s.ShiftID
```

Comment: you have two leaves of the concerned employee, so it presents the data as it should.

Comment: Don't use `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` for alias names.  Use something that makes sense when you read the rest of the query, like `e`, `r`, `l`, `o`, and `s`.

Comment: First your output was different,so according to that i wrote query.Now you have change your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query inner joins Employee and Roster, which is fine so far. But then, for every one of those rows, it links to all the leave requests for that employee. So you get all the employees leave requests for each roster day, not just the appropriate ones. If employee 123 had a roster day on 2018-05-04 like some of the others, then you'd have four results, not just two. You need to change

```
LEFT JOIN
    Leave l ON e.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN
    Leave l ON e.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID AND r.Date = l.Date
```

You will also need to change the overtime join the same way, or you will end up with the same problem as soon as an employee gets multiple overtime rows, or multiple roster rows.

Comment: Thank you So much! Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Employee table(EmployeeID int,Username int,Passwords varchar(20),GivenName varchar(30)
,FamilyName varchar(50),TeamID int,ContactNo int,StaffType int)
insert into @Employee VALUES
  (123         ,123      ,'abc','John',' Snow',1,999,1)
  ,(1234        ,1234     ,'abcd','Jack','Waller',2,223,1)
  ,(12345       ,12345    ,'abcde',' Ali','Saw',1,123,1)
  ,(123456      ,123456   ,'abcdef','Peter','Peter',2,223,1)
  ,(1234567     ,1234567  ,'abcdeg','Bryan','Peter',1,333,1)

declare @Roster table(Duty_ID int,EmployeeID int,Dates date,ShiftType int,ShiftDuration decimal(4,2))
insert into @Roster VALUES
(2,123     ,'2018-05-05', 1 ,  '8.25')
,(4,1234    ,'2018-05-04', 1 , '8.25')
,(5,12345   ,'2018-05-05', 1 , '8.25')
,(7,123456  ,'2018-05-04', 1 , '8.25')
,(8,1234567 ,'2018-05-05', 1 , '8.25')

declare @Overtime table(OTID int,EmployeeID int,Dates date,OT_Duration int,OT_Reason varchar(30))
insert into @Overtime VALUES
 (2,1234,'2018-05-04',2,'Cover Duty')

declare @Leave table(LeaveID int,EmployeeID int,Dates date,Duration_Off int,Reason varchar(30))
insert into @Leave VALUES
 (3 ,123,'2018-05-05',2 ,'NIL')
 ,(4 ,123,'2018-05-06',4 ,'NIL')
```

you can discuss the performance issue also.Also how many data you will process at a time ?

```
 SELECT Dates
    ,tbl.EmployeeID
    ,GivenName
    ,FamilyName
    ,TeamID
    ,ShiftType
    ,ShiftDuration
    ,Duration_Off
    ,OT_Duration
    ,Total_Hours
FROM (
    SELECT r.Dates
        ,r.EmployeeID
        ,r.ShiftType
        ,r.ShiftDuration
        ,l.Duration_Off
        ,0 OT_Duration
        ,r.ShiftDuration - l.Duration_Off [Total_Hours]
    FROM @Roster R
    INNER JOIN @Leave L ON r.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID
        AND r.Dates = l.Dates

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.Dates
        ,r.EmployeeID
        ,r.ShiftType
        ,r.ShiftDuration
        ,0
        ,o.OT_Duration
        ,r.ShiftDuration + o.OT_Duration [Total_Hours]
    FROM @Roster R
    INNER JOIN @Overtime O ON r.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
        AND r.Dates = o.Dates
    ) tbl
INNER JOIN @Employee E ON tbl.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Output is according to first post by the user.